# VSTS unable to build a docker image

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, azure-devops

I have a simple out of the box VS2017 web api that I am trying to build a Docker Image for on VSTS and publish the image to Azure container registry. But its not working, error below:

```
2018-05-21T16:49:45.8481201Z Step 7/17 : COPY WebApi/WebApi.csproj WebApi/
2018-05-21T16:49:45.8503445Z COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder936381234/WebApi/WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
2018-05-21T16:49:45.8644972Z ##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder936381234/WebApi/WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
2018-05-21T16:49:45.8732546Z ##[error]/usr/local/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
```

Its a standard VS2017 solution.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 63537
EXPOSE 44369

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApi/WebApi.csproj WebApi/
RUN dotnet restore WebApi/WebApi.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApi
RUN dotnet build WebApi.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

.dockerignore

```
.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.*.yml
*/bin
*/obj
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapi:
    image: webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
```

I have tried all the suggested solutions by changing the .dockerignore file, deleting it etc etc.

Comment: the line `COPY WebApi/WebApi.csproj WebApi/`fails as `WebApi/WebApi.csproj`does not exist, so check why

Comment: Same configuration works locally.

Comment: Be aware that it matters in which folder you place the dockerfile, or respectively, in which folder you call the `docker build` command. Docker will take a snapshot of this folder (and all subfolders) and forward it to the docker deamon to process. I.e. your paths in the dockerfile must be **relative** to where you call the `docker build` command.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes by using the Docker Compose task from the build tasks agents.

Answer (score 10):

It is based on the build context to copy files, by default, the **Use Default Build Context option** is checked for **Docker** task, you need to uncheck this option and specify the corresponding path (same level of solution), for example `.` for root folder.

Comment: This solved my issue.  I'm not sure why they Default Build Context was causing it to not the path though.  Thanks.

Comment: Dude!! This saved me hours as I'm a Azure/Container noob. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Visual Studio 2019. This is what solved it for me:

1. Delete Dockerfile; copy your customizations somewhere if you made any!
2. Right click the project -> Add -> Docker support, this should generate a new docker file. Copy your custom stuff back in.
3. Right click the project -> Edit Project File.
4. Find this line `<DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>` and remove it.

Comment: I just did step 4 and this solved my issue.  Thanks captain

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` in the compose file should be - 
`context: ./WebApi`

As mentioned in other answer Docker build takes directory as `context` which is the root directory of contents it needs to build the image.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Docker instead of Docker Compose task from the build tasks agents. Change to Docker Compose and point to Docker compose file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had an unnecessary Dockerfile that was located in a subdirectory.

Since VSTS by default searches for the Dockerfile with `**/Dockerfile`, this unnecessary Dockerfile was used, resulting in a wrong context. The correct Dockerfile was ignored.